# is it possible to get deadlock when accessing the field directly

Tags: java

Usually for thread safety, we access the field using synchronized(lock).

If without using synchronized(lock) and access the field directly, can we encounter deadlock in some case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without synchronization, there is no deadlock, only data corruption and undefined behaviour.

Comment: i disagree. without synchronization, deadlocks are still possible. Source: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2001/jw-1012-deadlock.html

Comment: @Druv see my comment to your answer - the articles don't support this statement.

Comment: @Dhruv Gairola: No, deadlocks can only happen with (improper) synchronization. The synchronization may be in third-party code, but my answer is still valid. The article you mention is all about synchronization deadlocks.

Answer (score 3):

You can get any kinds of bugs when you use wrong (or no) synchronization.

You can't **directly** get a deadlock simply by accessing a field without a `synchronized` block, but it can *easily* **lead** to a deadlock indirectly.

That means that accessing the field itself will not block, but depending on what you do afterwards, it can lead to a state that is not expected and that subsequently leads to a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Monitors are concerned with mutual exclusion.

On the issue of deadlocks- it is not important what method you use. It's more important that certain [conditions](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/O.F.Rana/os/lectureos12/node2.html) be met. No matter what method you're using, unless those conditions are met, deadlocks cannot be avoided. Thus, even if you use synchronized, unless certain conditions are met, deadlocks cannot be avoided.

Comment: I think you mean you can still *have* (not avoid) deadlocks without using the synchronized keyword? And that you can't guarantee that "somewhere down the line" you *won't* encounter deadlocks?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Brian Goetz article. It was excellent, and yes, deadlock avoidance can be tricky.  However, the OP's question was whether it's possible to encounter a deadlock without using the 'synchronized' keyword.